# Why the need to call resolve()?

Tags: promise, reason, bucklescript

I am looking at an example of Reason at [A First Reason React app for Javascript developers](https://jamesfriend.com.au/a-first-reason-react-app-for-js-developers)

And I see that he is calling `Js.Promise.resolve` when using `bs-fetch`:

```
RepoData.fetchRepos()
  |> Js.Promise.then_(repoData => {
       handleReposLoaded(repoData);
       Js.Promise.resolve();
     })
  |> ignore;
```

I have seen similar code in BuckleScript code as well. For example in [Bucklescript Cookbook](https://github.com/glennsl/bucklescript-cookbook):

```
Js.Promise.(
  Fetch.fetch "https://api.github.com/users/reasonml-community/repos"
  |> then_ Fetch.Response.text
  |> then_ (fun text -> 
      text 
      |> names
      |> Array.iter Js.log 
      |> resolve)
  |> ignore
```

In JS we usually call `resolve` when we create a new promise, not when using a function that returns a promise. So why do we need to call `resolve` in the cases above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Js.Promise.then_` requires that a new promise is returned.

The reason is that es6 promises aren't soundly typed. The value returned in a `then` callback is dynamically either wrapped or (infinitely) flattened so that it always returns a promise, and never a nested promise. That means if we allow any value to be returned (`let then_: ((_ => 'a), Js.Promise.t(_)) => Js.Promise.t('a)`), and if that value is a promise (`'a` = `Js.Promise.t('b)`), it would have the return type `Js.Promise.t(Js.Promise.t('b))`, but the value returned will actually have been flattened to just a `Js.Promise.t('b)`.

Having `then_` accept only a promise from the callback alleviates this a bit by making it more obvious that you return a nested promise. It's still possible to `resolve` a promise however, so the type is still not sound, but it makes it a little bit harder to shoot yourself in the foot.

There will be a sound and elegant promise API in the (probably near) future, but since it's a non-trivial task to design and implement it'll take a bit of time to get it right.